# Eclipse + Android + Cocos2d-x: Why does the emulation only work once?

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I am just starting to learn `cocos2d-x` for `Android`, and understand how to create a new project (using `create-android-project.sh`), compiling the native code (using `build_native.sh`), then importing it into *Eclipse* as a new `Android` project (*New > Android Project > From source...*).

The first time I run the project it works great, but if I run it a second time, nothing shows up on screen and I get a force close after 30 seconds or so. Is the *Eclipse* import screwing something up? What could I be doing wrong? Do I need to build/clean/etc in a certain order?

Comment: Can you tell what are you getting in crash logs???

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that on 2.2 if you use the back button, rather than the home button or the 'power' button it will break your emulator. On 2.3.3 and up, it won't even let you use the back button.

If you delete the emulator and remake it, the problem seems to be solved (kinda).

Still trying to figure out how to get around this one for the app I am making, as it needs to support 2.2.